# Control how requests are distributed on a NLB cluster

Tags: windows-server-2003, nlb

We are testing an application on an NLB cluster. We notice that the requests are not being spread evenly between the servers in the NLB cluster.

Is there anyway do configure the requests to be spread evenly between the servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted by the other commentors, the main way to control distribution is by the port rule distribution weight.  You may also see an imbalance if your NLB group configuration changes (i.e. a host goes down or comes back up) and you are using affinity, where requests stay with their current server even if a change in the cluster means they would normally be sent to another server.

In that case each server would get an equal share of new traffic, but servers that have been up longer will have more existing connections.

Also, have you verified that this traffic is over the NLB address and not on each server's unique address?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the load weight of each NLB host to equal. You can do this by editing the port rule in the host properties of each host in the cluster.

Answer (score 1):

From within the NLBS Administrator you can set the ratio in terms of percentages.